# Convert from select sqlite command to NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I have this select line.

```
[TableProperties setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username='%@' AND id IN (SELECT  Max(id) FROM messages GROUP BY MD5) ",MobilyUserAccount] forKey:@"tableWhere"];
```

I want to change this select line to.

```
NSPredicate *findUser = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username='%@' AND id IN (SELECT  id==max(id) FROM messages GROUP BY MD5)",MobilyUserAccount];
```

when I make the application run I have this error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "username='%@' AND id IN (SELECT  id==max(id) FROM messages GROUP BY MD5)"'
```

please I need a help to convert first line to.

```
NSPredicate *findUser = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat]
```

thanks all

Comment: Do you use SQLite or Core Data? If this is for SQLite then you cannot use NSPredicate. If the question is for Core Data, then you have to show how the entity is defined.

Comment: i have update to my application first time i use SQLite but now i want to use Core Data

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing in the second part of your SQL, `SELECT  id==max(id) FROM messages`

Comment: You cannot simply convert an arbitrary SQLite database to Core Data, and you cannot convert an arbitrary SELECT statement to NSPredicate. I don't want to sound unfriendly, but did you read the "Core Data Programming Guide"?

Comment: Are you sure there also isn't an error in you SQL query? I'm interpreting here but the group by MD5 (if it's an MD5 hash value) whould return as many records as there are messages because MD5 values should be (with high probability) unique. Also what's the ID is it the users ID or the messages ID? In any case @Martin is right. You will need to build your NSPredicates from scratch, which might not be difficult.

Comment: @aLevelOfIndirection the id message id and it's work correctly on sql

Comment: @Anupdas it's damage between the masseges that have the same md5 like send group of number

Comment: Can you mention your use case, what are you trying to fetch or something. With out knowing your core data structure it would be difficult to give a suggestion.